# How do I set my popover to click instead of hover using bootstrap and fontawesome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried focus and manual, but those does not seem to work. Any help on this?

Script:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$("i.fa").popover({'trigger':'hover'});
```

HTML:

```
<i rel="popover" data-content="hey" class="fa fa-share-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

CSS:

```
[rel="popover"]{
        cursor: pointer;
        display:inline-block; /* chrome-fix */
    }
i.fa {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: how about `({'trigger':'click'});`

Comment: what version of bootstrap? seems to work fine for me with bs3 https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/oeNNWO

Comment: Thank you, @hansTheFranz! Also, how do I check the version?

Comment: @SarahJ.Smith you import it somewhere. should look like `<script src="js/bootstrap..."></script>` and in that `src` link you should have a number

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like this. Is this what you want?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("i.fa").on('click',function(){
    $(this).popover().toggleClass('show');
});;
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/zy9bfsj9/8/)